# Accessing shared folder between Windows 7 and Ubuntu VM from the VM?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, shared-folders, virtualization

I set a [shared folder](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) between my Ubuntu  VM (on VirtualBox) and Windows 7 host machine correctly. Now I have no idead how to access the shared folder from my VM. Any idea ? 
I tried the solution one could understand as shown on this picture. Each time I type the password of the host machine I got prompted to type it again and again:
[image]

Comment: This page is out of date and should be deleted.
It applies to outdated versions of Virtual-box and Ubuntu.
But, like lots of old info it's at the top of Google results.
For version Ubuntu 14.04 this works: [Mount VirtualBox shared folder on Ubuntu or Linux guest](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/mount-virtualbox-shared-folder-on-ubuntu-linux/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I just typed the wrong username to my Windows 7 host machine. Here is the proof that I succeeded to access to the shared folder:
[image]

Comment: I'm curious if you've heard of vagrant.  It's a way to use virtualbox and setup the shared folders seamlessly.

Answer (score 5):

If you are facing trouble in accessing your shared folder, you can try following.

First install Guest Additions.

- After installing Guest Addition, go to Devices -> Shared Folder form
  VirtualBox's menu and add you folder.
- Now make a directory using `sudo mkdir /media/windows`. This
  directory will be used as  mount point of shared folder.
- Once mount point has been created, mount your folder using `sudo
  mount -t vboxsf <folder_name> /media/windows`.

It will mount your folder in /media/windows.

If this method works perfectly add the last command in `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file.

Comment: It says `/sbin/mount.vboxsf mounting failed with the error: 'Protocol error'`

Comment: Users in a guest Ubuntu must be in the group `vboxsf` to be able to access shares.